# Need help traking down Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'list' was corrupted

Tags: c, runtime

So I am getting Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'list' was corrupted.
I have dug through the code and cant figure out where this error is occurring. Could someone look this over and tell me where I may be going wrong. To be up front this is a class assignment for a data structure and algorithm class. The teacher has accepted my code but told me I need to fix this error. I have been looking for days now and cant seem to find where it is. The only limitation on this project is that the main cannot be changed.
Thanks for your help.

Jason

list.h

```
typedef char Titem;

// Interface of list
typedef struct node *Tpointer;
typedef struct node {
    Titem item;
    Tpointer next;
    Tpointer first;

} Tnode;
typedef Tpointer Tlist;

void initialize_list (Tlist *list);
void insert_to_list_end(Tlist *list, Titem data);
void print_list (Tlist *list);
void cleanup_list(Tlist *list);
```

list.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

// Implementation of list (only obj is need in appl)
void initialize_list (Tlist list)
{
    list->first = NULL;
    list->next = NULL;
}

void cleanup_list(Tlist list)
{
    Tpointer aux1, aux2;

    aux1 = list->first;
    while (aux1 != NULL) 
   {
        aux2 = aux1->next;
        free(aux1);
        printf("\nDeleted"); //for testing purposes
        aux1 = aux2;
    }
    initialize_list(&list);
}

void insert_to_list_end(Tlist list, Titem data) 
{
Tpointer newnode;

newnode = (Tpointer) malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
newnode -> item = data;
if (list->first == NULL)
    list->first = newnode;       //first node
    else
    list->next->next = newnode;  //not first node
list->next = newnode;
list->next->next = NULL;
}

void print_list (Tlist list) 
{
    Tpointer what;

    printf("\nList 4 :");
    what = list->first;
    while (what != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", what->item);
        printf("\nNext is %d ", what->next);
        what = what->next;
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

// Application
int main (void)  {
    Tlist list;

    initialize_list(&list);
    insert_to_list_end(&list, 'a');
    insert_to_list_end(&list, 'b');
    insert_to_list_end(&list, 'c');
    insert_to_list_end(&list, 'd');

    print_list(&list);
    cleanup_list(&list);

    fflush(stdin); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` Causes an Undefined Behavior.I wonder how your teacher didn't point out that.

Comment: The teacher wrote the main.c.

Comment: The function declaration in `list.h` is not appropriate: `Tlist *list` should be replaced by `Tlist list`. And can you give more details about your error?

Comment: well the program runs fine and gives all the correct output. when I hit return to shut the window then this error shows. when I break it show the error at the end of the main.c file. basically at the closing bracket.

Comment: by the way you can take out the printf("\nNext is %d ", what->next); form the print_list function I was using that for debugging.

Comment: That's a killer typedef.  Use `typedef Tnode Tlist;` and fix the bugs.

Comment: part of the assignment is to make it work with that setup. So I cant change to typedef Tnode Tlist.

Answer (score 0):

A sane compiler does not even compile your list.c -

```
list.c:6: error: conflicting types for 'initialize_list'
list.h:13: note: previous declaration of 'initialize_list' was here
list.c:12: error: conflicting types for 'cleanup_list'
list.h:16: note: previous declaration of 'cleanup_list' was here
list.c: In function 'cleanup_list':
list.c:24: warning: passing argument 1 of 'initialize_list' from incompatible pointer type
list.c:6: note: expected 'Tlist' but argument is of type 'struct node **'
list.c: At top level:
list.c:27: error: conflicting types for 'insert_to_list_end'
list.h:14: note: previous declaration of 'insert_to_list_end' was here
list.c:41: error: conflicting types for 'print_list'
list.h:15: note: previous declaration of 'print_list' was here
```

- here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

void initialize_list(Tlist *list)
{
    *list = NULL;
}

void cleanup_list(Tlist *list)
{
    Tpointer aux1, aux2;
    if (!*list) return;
    aux1 = (*list)->first;
    while (aux1 != NULL) 
    {
        aux2 = aux1->next;
        free(aux1);
        printf("\nDeleted");        //for testing purposes
        aux1 = aux2;
    }
    initialize_list(list);
}

void insert_to_list_end(Tlist *list, Titem data) 
{
    Tpointer newnode;
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(Tnode));
    newnode->item = data;
    if (*list == NULL)                      //first node
        newnode->first = newnode;
    else                                //not first node
        ((*list)->next = newnode)->first = (*list)->first;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    *list = newnode;
}

void print_list(Tlist *list) 
{
    Tpointer what;
    printf("\nList 4 :");
    if (!*list) return;
    what = (*list)->first;
    while (what != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c ", what->item);
        printf("\nNext is %d ", what->next);
        what = what->next;
    }
}
```